# Scala: How to avoid var here

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I have a code snippet like this:

```
def until(terminationCond: List[A]=>Boolean, combiner: List[A]=>List[A] )(obj: List[A]): A = {
      var tempObj = obj
      while(!terminationCond(tempObj)) {
          tempObj = combiner(obj)
      }
    tempObj.head
    }
```

I am looking out a way to write this code from **functional programming** style, avoiding any **mutable** types.

Comment: This snippet `combiner(obj)` is, by definition, not FP because it is a function that repeatedly takes the same argument but returns different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the following a little more declarative than the explicitly recursive version:

```
def until[A](
  terminationCond: List[A] => Boolean,
  combiner: List[A] => List[A]
)(obj: List[A]): A =
  Stream.iterate(obj)(combiner).dropWhile(!terminationCond(_)).head.head
```

I.e. we create a stream of results by iteratively applying `combiner`, drop as long as the termination condition doesn't hold, and then return the head of the first for which it does.

Answer (score 4):

Using recursion:

```
@tailrec
def doUntilTerm(obj: List[A]) = 
          if (terminationCond(obj)) obj.head else doUntilTerm(obj)
```

Comment: if (terminationCond(obj)) obj.head else doUntilTerm(combine(obj))  

Otherwise right.