# Scala - How to avoid a var here

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability, var

I wonder if anybody knows how to avoid the var in the following pseudocode:

```
var cnt = theConstant
val theSequence = theMap.flapMap{case (theSet, theList) =>
  if (theSet.isEmpty) {
    // do something here with theList and return a sequence
  } else {
    cnt += 1
    // do something here with cnt and theList and return a sequence
  }}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve? I think you should reconsider the design, and not only this part of code.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could get an answer like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643246/scala-how-to-avoid-var-here) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117982/how-to-avoid-mutable-local-variables-in-scala)

Comment: This is funny. My question gets answered, and proves it is clear to the expert while it avoids unnecessary words. In the meantime ignorants who don't understand the question downvote it and put it on hold. Thanks again to Dima for the great answer just in time before it was put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of thing is done with `foldLeft`.
It starts with whatever initial value you give it as an argument, and then calls your function for each element of the collection with a tuple, where first element is the previous result of function evaluation (or the initial value), and the second one is the current element of the collection.

```
val (cnt, theSequence) = theMap.foldLeft(0 -> Nil) { 
  case ((cnt, seq), (set, list)) if set.isEmpty => (cnt, seq ++ whateverSequence) 
  case ((cnt, seq), (set, list)) => (cnt + 1, seq ++ whateverSequence)
}
```

You can also use a recursive solution:

```
@tailrec 
def countAndSeq[K,V,T](in: List[(Set[K], List[V]], cnt: Int = 0, seq: List[T] = Nil) = in match {
  case Nil => cnt -> seq
  case (set, list) :: tail if set.isEmpty => countAndSeq(tail, cnt, seq ++ whatever)
  case (set, list) :: tail => countAndSeq(tail, cnt+1, seq ++ whatever)
```

}

```
val (cnt, seq) = countAndSeq(theMap.toList)
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! I have tried it in my code and it runs beautifully. Thank you very much for solving my problem and for answering just before it was put on hold.